# Get string name with double spaces

Tags: joomla-3.x, jinput

I have one string value such as `The string contains double  spaces`.
I am fetching this string as:

```
$string = $jinput->get('sports', '','raw');
```

It returns me correct result when there are no double spaces in a string. But, if there is a double space as above example, it omits the double space and gives:
`The string contains double spaces`

I want to get the string value as it is. Any idea how can I get this?

Answer (score 1):

This is weird. `raw` simply returns the value of the field with no filtering whatsoever (see `libraries/joomla/filter/input.php`). However, it might be that there is some other filtering done before or after your code. Check to see if $_GET['sports'] has the same problem, if it does, then it is likely caused by a server setting somewhere. If it doesn't, then the culprit is either the Joomla core or a Joomla plugin.

You can always use $_GET to retrieve your values, but make sure you do the proper filtering on the values retrieved in order to prevent an attack.